how to have hidden credentials on a git repo
I want to push a version of a credentials file with the keys removed, then modify it locally with the correct keys, and have that local file not pushed (added to git ignore). I have been so far unable to achieve this.

This seems like an XY Problem. The usual solution is to store the credentials in a dedicated secrets manager. You can add a file to .gitignore to ignore changes in it, but that doesn't prevent you from manually making changes.

You could just upload a template for the credential file instead, making it clear that the user of the repository has to copy it, name it something specific, and fill in their credentials.

Appears this cannot be done, have instead removed the file from git, added to gitignore then created the same file with .example extension and pushed that.

It is actually a common problem, and yeah, there isn't an actual solution.
But a colleague of mine actually achieved this by using git update-index --skip-worktree command, since we have the same problem on a .run IntelliJ configuration.
You can find more documentation here, hope it comes in handy.
